# Carry bag product photography

Tags: product-photography, light

[image]

This is my project to challenge myself this week.
Getting a professional product photography done for a transparent/ semitransparent carry bag.

Challenges
- it doesn't not have a firm shape
- lighting the bag
- showing the functionality of the bag

I do not wanna just take photos of the empty carry bag lying on a surface.

Do you guys have anything on this?

Comment: Do you have access to a dolphin or a sea turtle?  Or any other single use plastic products?

Comment: The intention of Stack Exchange sites is to answer questions and solve specific problems. It's like a FAQ. Your question - an open-ended request for ideas - is not really a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to 500px.com where I did a keyword search for "carrying bag:" https://500px.com/search?submit=Submit+Query&q=carrying+bag&type=photos

You should find some good ideas.  I'd also encourage you to use a better looking bag than just a white plastic bag from a grocery store.

Having items sticking up from the top of the bag is a commonly used way of showing the usefulness of the bag.  Having someone hold the bag adds that human element which adds quite a lot to an image.

Think of a time where you use the bag, and then set up a scene to tell that story.  Maybe it's a boy walking with his father each with fishing poles on their shoulders.  The boy is holding a bag with fish.

Maybe you could have two friends about to make dinner together and one is pulling a bottle of their favorite beverage out of a bag and giving it to their friend.

The idea here is to get away from the sterile product shot and instead, tell a story with the item.

Comment: Well, as @dav1dsmith hints at above, the current story behind single-use plastic bags is the environmental damage they are doing. They're about to be banned in the EU.